# Laravel queue not reading updates from Kernel.php

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon

### Background

I have a laravel project that has been running fine for a number of weeks now and has been running a scheduled job every 5 minutes with no problem. I can see this job being ran in Horizon and if I use `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` I also see the job running. FYI - I use Redis for the queue driver.

### The working Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;

use Artisan;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Jobs\FetchMajorProblems;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
        'App\Console\Commands\MassAssignRole',
        'App\Console\Commands\ClearLogs',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

       $schedule->command('horizon:snapshot')->everyFiveMinutes();

       $schedule->job(new FetchMajorProblems)->everyFiveMinutes();

    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

### The Issue

I have now created a new job in exactly the same way as I did for `FetchMajorProblems`. I have also now added this to the Kernel.php file via the following 2 changes;

- Added `use App\Jobs\FetchMajorIncidents;` to the top.
- Added `$schedule->job(new FetchMajorIncidents)->everyFiveMinutes();` to the schedule function.

However, The new `FetchMajorIncidents` job is not being called.

### What I have tried

I have tried the following:

- Restarted horizon
- Restarted the server
- Cleared the php cache
- Cleared the php config
- Cleared the php views
- Ran Composer dump-autoload

As a test I also tried to remove the current job by commenting out `$schedule->job(new FetchMajorProblems)->everyFiveMinutes();`. The issue is that even though this is commented out, the job is still being ran every 5 minutes!

I can't think of anything else to check where the jobs may be being cached.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. Is the job being called or not?

Comment: Scheduled jobs are not run via queue but via cronjob. Are you sure you check the right place?

Comment: You are spot on, after everything I did, I was still running scheduler from an old project directory that just to happened to have the same FetchMajorProblems job. Updated the cron task to be the correct directory and all is working again. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.